# What is wrong with my angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an Angular's custom directive that allows users to set up a title. However, it seems not work as expected.

```
app.directive('appTitle', function () {
    var myTitle = {};
    myTitle.restrict = 'E';
    myTitle.scope = {
        //title: '='
        title: 'title='
    };
    myTitle.transclude = true;
    myTitle.template = "<div class='jumbotron'><h1 class='text-center'>
    {{text}}</h1><div class='text-center' data-ng-transclude></div></div>";
    return myTitle;
});
```

It is used like this in HTML (Description works well but title not):

```
<app-title title="This is a title">This is a description.</app-title>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't described the problem. Where is {{text}} being defined on the scope?

Comment: `title: '='` should work fine. but not `title: 'title='` it should be `title: '=title'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, because you're passing a String to the directive.

```
myTitle.scope = {
    title: '@'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

The first, your scope assignment is wrong. Change it to:

```
myTitle.scope = {
    title: '='
    // or
    // title: '=title'
};
```

And the second, you have to pass the title as String i.e. in quotes since this will interpolate:

```
<app-title title="'This is a title'">This is a description.</app-title>
```

**Edit**

What I mentioned is Two way binding i.e. if you change the title being passed to the directive, it will update the directive's template as well.

See an example of the same below. It's based on your requirement.

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

});

app.directive('appTitle', function () {
    var myTitle = {};
    myTitle.restrict = 'E';
    myTitle.scope = {
        title: '='
    };
    myTitle.transclude = true;
    myTitle.template = "<div class='jumbotron'><h1 class='text-center'>"+
    "{{title}}</h1><div class='text-center' data-ng-transclude></div></div>";
    return myTitle;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <input ng-model="myTitle" />
  <app-title title="myTitle">This is a description.</app-title>
</div>
```

So if you use `title: '='` in the `scope` you can pass attribute like below:

```
<app-title title="'This is a title'">This is a description.</app-title>
<app-title title="anScopeVariableOrModel">This is a description.</app-title>
```

And if you use `title: '@'` then the above two will be written as:

```
<app-title title="This is a title">This is a description.</app-title>
<app-title title="{{anScopeVariableOrModel}}">This is a description.</app-title>
```

Comment: There's no need for two-way binding if all you're providing is a string.

Comment: @Makoto Good to know that. Thanks.